# Sipmle Form For - displaying a value different from the model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form-for

I have a form where I wish to perform a calculation on a date before displaying it. The model has a field for start, and a method adjusted_start and adjusted_finish which I want to display instead of the raw attribute.

I've tried:

```
f.input :start, as: time, label: false, minute_step: 5, value: openingtime.adjuted_start
```

However this is over ridden with the raw 'start' attribute. Is there any way to get it to display a different value than the one it has stored for start?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should be `input_html: { value: openingtime.adjuted_start }`.
You need to wrap html attributes in `input_html` hash.
Check out [doc](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#usage).